# Switching users inside Docker image to a non-root user

Tags: linux, bash, git, docker, debian

I'm trying to switch user to the tomcat7 user in order to setup SSH certificates.

When I do `su tomcat7`, nothing happens.

`whoami` still ruturns root after doing `su tomcat7`

Doing a `more /etc/passwd`, I get the following result which clearly shows that a tomcat7 user exists:

```
root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash
daemon:x:1:1:daemon:/usr/sbin:/bin/sh
bin:x:2:2:bin:/bin:/bin/sh
sys:x:3:3:sys:/dev:/bin/sh
sync:x:4:65534:sync:/bin:/bin/sync
games:x:5:60:games:/usr/games:/bin/sh
man:x:6:12:man:/var/cache/man:/bin/sh
lp:x:7:7:lp:/var/spool/lpd:/bin/sh
mail:x:8:8:mail:/var/mail:/bin/sh
news:x:9:9:news:/var/spool/news:/bin/sh
uucp:x:10:10:uucp:/var/spool/uucp:/bin/sh
proxy:x:13:13:proxy:/bin:/bin/sh
www-data:x:33:33:www-data:/var/www:/bin/sh
backup:x:34:34:backup:/var/backups:/bin/sh
list:x:38:38:Mailing List Manager:/var/list:/bin/sh
irc:x:39:39:ircd:/var/run/ircd:/bin/sh
gnats:x:41:41:Gnats Bug-Reporting System (admin):/var/lib/gnats:/bin/sh
nobody:x:65534:65534:nobody:/nonexistent:/bin/sh
libuuid:x:100:101::/var/lib/libuuid:/bin/sh
messagebus:x:101:104::/var/run/dbus:/bin/false
colord:x:102:105:colord colour management daemon,,,:/var/lib/colord:/bin/false
saned:x:103:106::/home/saned:/bin/false
tomcat7:x:104:107::/usr/share/tomcat7:/bin/false
```

What I'm trying to work around is this error in Hudson:

```
Command "git fetch -t git@________.co.za:_______/_____________.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*" returned status code 128: Host key verification failed.
```

This is my Dockerfile, it takes an existing hudson war file and config that is tarred and builds an image, hudson runs fine, it just can't access git due to certificates not existing for user tomcat7.

```
FROM debian:wheezy

# install java on image
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y openjdk-7-jdk tomcat7

# install hudson on image
RUN rm -rf /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/*
ADD ./ROOT.tar.gz /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/

# copy hudson config over to image
RUN mkdir /usr/share/tomcat7/.hudson
ADD ./dothudson.tar.gz /usr/share/tomcat7/
RUN chown -R tomcat7:tomcat7 /usr/share/tomcat7/

# add ssh certificates
RUN mkdir /root/.ssh
ADD ssh.tar.gz /root/

# install some dependencies
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install --y maven
RUN apt-get install --y git
RUN apt-get install --y subversion

# background script
ADD run.sh /root/run.sh
RUN chmod +x /root/run.sh

# expose port 8080
EXPOSE 8080


CMD ["/root/run.sh"]
```

I'm using the latest version of Docker (Docker version 1.0.0, build 63fe64c/1.0.0), is this a bug in Docker or am I missing something in my Dockerfile?

Comment: Are you aware of the [`USER`](http://docs.docker.com/reference/builder/#user) Dockerfile instruction?

Comment: Nope, what do you suggest I use it for?

Comment: Would it be possible to generate certificates via the Dockerfile using the USER instruction?

Comment: Everything you `RUN` after a `USER` instruction is done under the corresponding uid, so although I'm not sure I perfectly understand your problem, it looks it might be what you're looking for.

Comment: @icecrime not everything, unfortunately. `COPY` creates files as uid 0, which means they are not writable by the non-root user, and running `RUN chown ...` on those files won't work unless the current user is also root. So one ends up switching back and forth between root and the other user throughout the Dockerfile.

Comment: So what is  the approach to take if you need to switch user in the middle of a RUN command that contains a chain of unix commands? e.g. `RUN start some service && su myuser && other cmds to run while service is running but need to run as myuser`

Comment: split the chain, that's the only way.

Comment: You should note that the user `tomcat7` has a login shell of `/bin/false`, which means that normally a `su` would fail, however a `sudo` may succeed.  Either way, the `USER tomcat7` command would be the best way.

Answer (score 177, accepted):

You should not use `su` in a [dockerfile](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#user), however you should use the `USER` instruction in the Dockerfile.

At each stage of the [Dockerfile](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#user) build, a new container is created so any change you make to the user will not persist on the next build stage.

For example:

```
RUN whoami
RUN su test
RUN whoami
```

This would never say the user would be `test` as a new container is spawned on the 2nd whoami. The output would be root on both (unless of course you run USER beforehand).

If however you do:

```
RUN whoami
USER test
RUN whoami
```

You should see `root` then `test`.

Alternatively you can run a command as a different user with sudo with something like

```
sudo -u test whoami
```

But it seems better to use the official supported instruction.

Comment: I'm curious about how to make sure previously run commands are available to the user set in the Dockerfile. [I have a question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36183585/how-can-one-influence-the-order-of-run-commands-in-a-dockerfile) where folders and permissions previously set by root are not available after switching to another user with the `USER` instruction.

Comment: You might need `COPY --chown=myuser ...` down the road.

Comment: How to run multiple commands as different users in a single RUN? Will `RUN sudo su user && command1 && sudo su user2 && command2` work?

Answer (score 64):

As a different approach to the other answer, instead of indicating the user upon image creation on the Dockerfile, you can do so via command-line on a particular container as a per-command basis.

With `docker exec`, use `--user` to specify which user account the interactive terminal will use (the container should be running and the user has to exist in the containerized system):

```
docker exec -it --user [username] [container] bash
```

See https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/exec/

Answer (score 30):

In case you need to perform privileged tasks like changing permissions of folders you can perform those tasks as a root user and then create a non-privileged user and switch to it.

```docker
FROM <some-base-image:tag>

# Switch to root user
USER root # <--- Usually you won't be needed it - Depends on base image

# Run privileged command
RUN apt install <packages>
RUN apt <privileged command>

# Set user and group
ARG user=appuser
ARG group=appuser
ARG uid=1000
ARG gid=1000
RUN groupadd -g ${gid} ${group}
RUN useradd -u ${uid} -g ${group} -s /bin/sh -m ${user} # <--- the '-m' create a user home directory

# Switch to user
USER ${uid}:${gid}

# Run non-privileged command
RUN apt <non-privileged command>
```

Comment: I had problems using `USER ${uid}:${gid}`. If you add the user to other groups, the memberships are lost like this (say if you the flag `-G video,sudo,dialout`). Using just `USER ${uid}` solves the issue.

Answer (score 13):

Add this line to docker file

```
USER <your_user_name>
```

Use docker instruction [USER](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#user)

Answer (score 6):

You should also be able to do:

`apt install sudo`

`sudo -i -u tomcat`

Then you should be the tomcat user.  It's not clear which Linux distribution you're using, but this works with Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, for example.

Answer (score -12):

There's no real way to do this.  As a result, things like mysqld_safe fail, and you can't install mysql-server in a Debian docker container without jumping through 40 hoops because.. well... it aborts if it's not root.

You can use USER, but you won't be able to apt-get install if you're not root.