# Create user in ubuntu docker instead using root

Tags: ubuntu, meteor, docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I am creating a custom docker image based on ubuntu (`testing:latest`). I want to run some unit tests for a meteor application.

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04
RUN apt-get update -y && \
    apt-get install -yqq --no-install-recommends apt-transport-https ca-certificates curl nodejs-legacy && \
    apt-get clean && apt-get autoclean && apt-get autoremove && \
    curl https://install.meteor.com/ | sh && \
    meteor npm install eslint eslint-plugin-react && \
    apt-get remove -y apt-transport-https ca-certificates curl && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
```

I am using gitlab CI using a **docker** runner. So my yml file looks like

```
stages:
  - test

lint:
  image: testing:latest
  stage: test
  script:
    - /node_modules/.bin/eslint --ext .js --ext .jsx .
  except:
    - master

unit:
  image: testing:latest
  stage: test
  script:
    - whoami
    - meteor test --driver-package=practicalmeteor:mocha-console-runner
  except:
    - master
```

Running `whoami` shows me that the current user is `root`. Therefore meteor test is not running, as it shouldn't be used with `root`

```
You are attempting to run Meteor as the 'root' superuser. If you are
developing, this is almost certainly *not* what you want to do and will likely
result in incorrect file permissions. However, if you are running this command
in a build process (CI, etc.), or you are absolutely sure you know what you are
doing, set the METEOR_ALLOW_SUPERUSER environment variable or pass
--allow-superuser to proceed.

Even with METEOR_ALLOW_SUPERUSER or --allow-superuser, permissions in your app
directory will be incorrect if you ever attempt to perform any Meteor tasks as
a normal user. If you need to fix your permissions, run the following command
from the root of your project:

  sudo chown -Rh <username> .meteor/local
```

How can I use another user? Do I have to do that in the dockerfile? Or do I have to add some commands in the yml file?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do it the normal Ubuntu way `RUN useradd <username>` then `USER <username>` and run the task.

[From the Docker.Io Docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#user)

> The `USER` instruction sets the user name or UID to use when running the image and for any `RUN`, `CMD` and `ENTRYPOINT` instructions that follow it in the `Dockerfile`.

You can also look at this SO Answer: [Switching users inside Docker image to a non-root user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24549746/switching-users-inside-docker-image-to-a-non-root-user)